# Error with the setListAdapter and getListview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I got the Error about

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ACTIVITY_CHOICES));
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

I just learn to develop on android.

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            final String[] ACTIVITY_CHOICES = new String[] {getString(R.string.menu_new_game),getString(R.string.menu_prefs)};

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ACTIVITY_CHOICES));
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        }
        OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){

            switch(arg2)
                   {
                     case 0:
                     startGame();
                     break;
                     case 1:
                     startPrefs();
                     break;
                     default: break;
              }
        }getListView().setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);   
      };      

      private void startGame() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("memoryPrefs", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefeditor = settings.edit();
        prefeditor.putBoolean("new_game", true);
        prefeditor.putInt("score", 100);
        prefeditor.commit();
        Intent launchGame = new Intent(this, PlayGame.class);
        startActivity(launchGame);
    }

    private void startPrefs() {
          Intent launchPrefs = new Intent(this, SettingScreen.class);
          startActivity(launchPrefs);
        }


   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();        
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("memoryPrefs", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefeditor = settings.edit();
    prefeditor.putString("previous_screen", "MenuScreen");
    prefeditor.commit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Post your logcat error details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. public class MainActivity extends **ListActivity**
2. add listview id as **android:id="@android:id/list"** in activity_main.xml file

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend `ListActivity`.

`setListAdapter` is a method of `LisActivtiy`.

Change this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
```

Also the below

```
 getListView().setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);
```

should be `onCreate`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

**ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)**

So if you need other views in your xml you need to have

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" // in your layout xml
```

If you don't want any other view remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Or you need to have `ListView` in xml. Initialize listview and use

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final String[] ACTIVITY_CHOICES = new String[] {getString(R.string.menu_new_game),getString(R.string.menu_prefs)};
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ACTIVITY_CHOICES));
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);
    }
    OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){

        switch(arg2)
               {
                 case 0:
                 startGame();
                 break;
                 case 1:
                 startPrefs();
                 break;
                 default: break;
          }
    }   
  };      

  private void startGame() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("memoryPrefs", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefeditor = settings.edit();
    prefeditor.putBoolean("new_game", true);
    prefeditor.putInt("score", 100);
    prefeditor.commit();
    Intent launchGame = new Intent(this, PlayGame.class);
    startActivity(launchGame);
}

private void startPrefs() {
      Intent launchPrefs = new Intent(this, SettingScreen.class);
      startActivity(launchPrefs);
    }


@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();        
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("memoryPrefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefeditor = settings.edit();
prefeditor.putString("previous_screen", "MenuScreen");
prefeditor.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your lines to like below and see if any errors and extend to ListActivity

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final String[] ACTIVITY_CHOICES = new String[] {getString(R.string.menu_new_game),getString(R.string.menu_prefs)};
```